# Персонаж в Unity2D проходит через препятствия

Tags: unity3d

Делаю top down 2D игру, создал персонажа, добавил препятствия, но сколько чего не пробовал,
персонаж проходит через них.

И коллайдеры висят, и Rigidbody, и у игрока ставил dynamic, и у них, и на одном слое они стоят.

Может что-то в скрипте не так?
Скрипт я скопировал из инета, но перепроверил несколько раз, вроде.

P.S Помогло решение убиранием галочки, но, хочу добавить для остальных, если у вас после этого персонаж начнет крутиться при столкновении с объектами, просто заморозьте движение по оси z в Rigidbody2D

[image: настройки препятствия]

[image: настройки персонажа]

```
using UnityEngine 
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class player_move : MonoBehaviour{

new Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

public Animator anim;

public float movementSpeed;

void Awake()
{
    rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    targetVelocity = targetVelocity.normalized;
    anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", targetVelocity.x);
    anim.SetFloat("Vertical", targetVelocity.y);
    anim.SetFloat("Magnitude", targetVelocity.magnitude);


    Move(targetVelocity);

    
}

void Move(Vector2 targetVelocity)
{        
    rigidbody2D.velocity = (targetVelocity * movementSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У коллайдера значение `IsTrigger` поставь `False` (или же, если по простому, убери галочку)